# My question is deleted, I am not allowed to ask more questions. Are these really good practices?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I asked [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/402639/mbnm-measuringbynotmeasuring-thought-experiment-is-this-wrong-if-so-how) question which I later learned was apparently preposterous and was heavily downvoted.

I was still positive that someone will one day come across my question who will be generous and patient enough to look through my question and help me understand it better.

So a few days ago I wanted to check the status of the question, but to my surprise, I did not find it in my list of asked questions. And then I looked through my "all actions" tab and "reputation" tab entries. *Nowhere!!*

After like 30 mins of search, fortunately, I found an old conversation of mine, in a chat room, where I had mentioned the link to my question, So I was able to retrieve the question. And it said to undelete the question it required votes.

**How are the upvotes from others are possible if you hide the question from everyone?**

So I commented the link to this question, on my other questions requesting users to analyze it and **upvote for the undeletion** if they found it right. But then I get a private  message from moderators, that such commenting is not in line with the spirit of the website and I should instead ask in meta site or a chat room, which I found completely justified, so I messaged them back apologizing and told them that I would delete the comments that I posted on my questions requesting the undeletion and I go onto delete the comments, again to my surprise all of my comments are **deleted without my permission.**

I find this totally wrong on so many levels.

**Firstly**, we already have the privilege of downvoting the question. If we find someone's question to be inappropriate we can downvote it vehemently, but we should not have the privilege of deleting the question for who knows, after some time there may come new visitors who will upvote the question more, so by deleting it you are preventing the self-correcting mechanism of society. By deleting a question you are removing a data sample from the public access and I believe it is a violent invasion of freedom of speech. And the reason that is given is

> Abandoned, unanswered questions can be a nuisance for readers when
> they appear in search results. While every question deserves a chance
> to be answered, at some point the annoyance to those searching for a
> solution outweighs the increasingly small chance that an answer will
> be provided.
>
> For this reason, the Community user will automatically delete old
> abandoned / dead questions in the following circumstances:

"at some point the annoyance to those searching for a solution outweighs the increasingly small chance that an answer will be provided". This is dangerous as this chooses **practicality over truth**. That is not how science works, we will have to examine extremely annoying ideas and take on ordeals, to come to the truth of reality. **Instead of deleting the question, question with high downvotes can be shown in the end, therefore fixing nuisance problem.** And people who are searching the answer will notice the downvotes and will not engage in that question. Why don't we let people decide for themselves? Rather than saying here is a question, which many people think is bad, see if you want to spend time on it, it is objectively worse to hide that question from the "those searching for a solution". A question is not an atomic statement. The question and its description can layout an unprecedented way of thinking which can bring forth valuable insights. By deleting the question all this organic nuanced dynamic is thrown out of the window.

**Secondly**, even though we can delete the question, why are we removing every reference of the question, almost obsessively, from the website. In my personal profile, the question is deleted from my list of asked questions. How can we do it? Not just that, every reference of the question, from "all actions" and "reputation" entries is also erased? This was absolutely unnecessary, if I did not have the link to my own question somehow, I would have lost my question, I could have had some potentially valuable information or insight into that question. This is absolutely not acceptable, as this is almost equivalent to the destruction of my private data and infringement of my privacy and my access to my own data.

**Thirdly**, I can't ask any question, because if I try to ask a question it says

> "You have reached your question limit Sorry, we are no longer
> accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn
> more."

Seriously? If we think that someone is not contributing to the community, we can take away that person's reputation. It is one of the purpose of reputation. But we simply cannot excommunicate the user. It seems to be a redundant functionality. And it's also not very effective, because all that someone needs to do is create a new account and start asking questions. This does not fix anything. Instead if we feel like someone is not genuine we can take the reputation off or make his/her reputation negative.  So that particular person will obviously be neglected. And if some one spams with like 100 questions, I think we already have a system that you cannot ask more than one question in a fixed window time period. And lets say if a person just goes on asking gibberish, there should an upper-limit of questions for given reputation-downvote based history of previously asked questions. This is way better solution as compared to ban someone who has asked like 10 questions in my case.

**In summary** I agree there should be some measures to ensure the ease and quality of the website. And we do have such measures like downvoting, flagging, reputation loss. But I argue that deleting someone's question, and also banning that person from asking questions and obsessively removing references of the question thereby effectively taking away the access to the question, even to the person who asked it, is a blatant invasion of privacy and a violation of freedom of speech. A conflation of moderation with censoring. And a set of redundant unnecessary features which are arguably not the best practices in the field of Science, where truth is of the highest value.

I predict that this question will be met with rigorous downvoting, will be put on hold as off-topic or opinion-based, and in a couple of days closed and in a week or a month deleted and wiped clean from the face of this website. **And then someone writes a blog on why stack exchange is hostile to newcomers. Seriously?**

And I also speculate if **Einstein** was to be born in this day and age and asks something which is non-populistic, he will not be discussed with, instead his questions will be downvoted, he will be banned from asking questions, his questions will be wiped clean by the "routine" in turn operated by "moderators". This is not Science, this is online-mob-censoring.

P.S: Please do not confuse this with me blaming moderators and SE users. I am aware that deletion and banning happens automatically by present routine. And that is exactly what I am talking against here. This is me trying to point out that the present rules which guide the routine as of now, allow for blatant invasion of freedom of speech and privacy.

Comment: No permission whatsoever is needed to delete your comments. Comments aren't meant to last anyway.

Comment: Newcomers perceive hostility because they misunderstand the purpose of Stack Exchange. Honestly I would have been in for a rigorous discussion here if every single concern you have wasn't already addressed numerous times. Please feel free to look around using site search, it's full of these discussions. Bottom line is, Stack Exchange is meant to help people collectively by building a repository of knowledge, not helping individuals like a help desk.

Comment: And the "just as I predicted" attitude is not very helpful in having a constructive discussion. There is no monopoly here, so if you assumed you were going to get downvoted, which you seem to equate with being ignored, why did you spend such amount of time in the first place? In fact, I did downvote, and precisely because you could have spent a quarter of your time looking around and finding the answers for yourself.

Comment: @M.A.R.ಠ_ಠ I do understand that stack-ex is not akin to a help desk. And when you say "building a repository of knowledge" , if some asks something, which you deem as unfit to be included in the repository of knowledge, My concern here exactly is that deleting the question and every reference of it may not be the most beneficial thing to do, as the very heuristics used to consider what is to be to be added to repository may be flawed or incomplete.

Comment: @M.A.R.ಠ_ಠ and as for other discussions addressing the same concerns I will definitely look around.

Comment: @M.A.R.ಠ_ಠ "just as i predicted" I promise is not coming from an attitude, but just that my analysis was correct. I am clearly differentiating between getting ignored and getting downvoted, that was the whole point of my question. That is we can ignore someone but I think it's not best in our interest to delete what a person has said. As for looking around, I did, but in my admittedly limited search I didn't find questions discussing my concerns enough to reflect what I had in my mind

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179159/why-did-you-block-my-stack-overflow-account-for-asking-a-question-here/179162#179162 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222585/user-being-downvoted-for-personal-reasons/222590#222590 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243317/proposal-against-power-abuse-on-stack-sites-and-a-more-democratic-voting-system/243327#243327

Comment: cross-posted from the local meta: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10919/50583 For the record, I didn't really intend for you to repost the whole rant verbatim here, but focus more clearly on the problems with the automatic question deletion routine you claim to have meant.

Comment: Stack Exchange isn't a place for science, in the sense of doing primary research and grappling with the very edges of what can be known. Rather, it's a place for well-understood knowledge and expertise to be shared, and it's heavily optimized for accessibility, ease of searching, and minimizing distractions and irritations for answerers and searchers.

Comment: "Stack Exchange isn't a place for science, in the sense of doing primary research and grappling with the very edges of what can be known" if that is so, then I have to concede that I am totally wrong.

Comment: @myasadefa It's not with looking better, I have had extended discussions on private chat room. One of the main contributors of phy.SE when I cornered him with my argument, he ended up telling that if your thought experiment contradicts Heisenberg Uncertainty principle so much bad for you thought experiment. The very idea of this appalls them.

Comment: @myasadefa the very idea that I'm proposing against HUP is appalling to them

Comment: @myasadefa I saw in many videos and in many articles they were telling HUP is ontological. Then when I went in search of why it was ontological , I could not find it. So I asked https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/402793/which-experiment-clearly-shows-us-that-heisenberg-uncertainty-principle-is-ontol to which no clear reply came. My whole point was to suggest we do not have enough proof to conclude HUP is ontological instead of epistemological.

Comment: @myasadefa HUP means Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle

Answer (score 23):

Let's start with your first remark

> again to my surprise all of my comments are deleted without my permission.

Just to be clear, no permission whatsoever is needed to delete your comments. Comments are meant to clarify the content above it, and can be deleted at any time, for any reason. They are not guaranteed at all to stick around. See [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

> we should not have the privilege of deleting the question for who knows, after sometime there may come new visitors who will upvote the question more, so by deleting it you are preventing the self correcting mechanism of society.

Content can perhaps gain traction after some time. So the first downvote or negative response should not be a reason for deletion. But there is plenty of content that doesn't need to stick around ad infinitum in the hope that it magically gets upvotes later on. Content can be bad, complete off-topic, insulting or simply not a fit for the site. There's plenty of room for improvement, even after deletion, to get your post back up again, so deletion is not an issue. Now if you take issue with the motivation for the deletion of your particular question, that's something to take up with the site-specific Meta. Or if you fell victim to automatic deletion, and you don't understand the downvotes you got, again, discuss it on the Meta. But overall deletion is not a problem.

> why are we removing every reference of the question, almost obsessively, from the website

Why should we keep it around. Most users won't be able to visit it anyway. Only high-rep users could. The community has deemed it's not good/appropriate content, so why explicitly keep a path to it around? And you can still find it within your [recently deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/what-is-the-deleted-recent-questions-page-in-the-user-profile).

> Thirdly, I can't ask any question

See [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) You won't get banned for a single poorly received question, so there must be more to it.

In summary, there is no problem with deletion, your permission is not required, and if you feel your content was deleted for the wrong reasons, you should take it up with your community.

Comment: I didn't know the volatility of comments. This is new. But you said you can find your questions in recently deleted questions. But its only recently deleted questions. After some time it will get erased from there also. As in my case I can't find my deleted questions in recently deleted quesiton

Comment: So they weren't recently deleted? If you don't care enough about your deleted content to either notice it, or to fix it up to where it can be undeleted ... why should anyone else care? Why should it hang around and muck up the site?

Comment: "So the first downvote or negative response should not be a reason for deletion. But there is plenty of content that doesn't need to stick around ad infinitum in the hope that it magically gets upvotes later on. Content can be bad, complete off-topic, insulting or simply not a fit for the site" insulting and abusive  ad-hominem questions are a kind which are fit to be discarded. But questions completely respectful, but still commonly deemed off-topic and bad can be voted so, but deletion is too much. Because you essentially removing data from public

Comment: this is cyclical, I did notice it try to engage with dowvoters in a discussion. That is why my question wanted 3 votes for undeleting. But if it doesn't get voted for undeletion, which is completely at the mercy of downvoters, that question will get permanently deleted. And even I will lose access to my own quesiton

Comment: And what logical reason do you give for taking it of my asked question list

Comment: "questions completely respectful, but still commonly deemed off-topic and bad can be voted so, but deletion is too much". No it's not. I can ask a very respectful question about pancakes on the Physics SE. Doesn't mean it should hang around. I get the impression you know all this, you understand all this, but just don't want it to apply to you. "Removing data from the public" is up to the site. You licensed it to them, they can decide not to use it (or keep it around for ever and ever). Nothing stops you from making it available somewhere else. You just don't get to tell the site what to do.

Comment: Why would we keep such questions on your asked question list? Every user is allowed to screw up at some point. Why keep it in their profile after it has been deleted? Why always show the black marks? It's not available to most anyway, so don't show it in the profile. You as the OP have plenty of time to do something to prevent deletion. If such actions aren't taken, or aren't successful, there's no need to leave a black mark on your profile when we won't even show it on the site.

Comment: But you can't make that decision on my behalf. You must leave it  to me. If I don't want to delete it you should not be able to delete it atleast in my private profile for protecting myself from my black marks. It must be my choice

Comment: "You as the OP have plenty of time to do something to prevent deletion" there isn't and prevention is completely at the mercy of someone else.

Comment: Prevention is up to the quality if your content. You have plenty of time. Automatic deletion doesn't kick in immediately. If you take none of the opportunities you're given, you don't get to complain once it's over.

Comment: I think you are mixing up my two different concerns, one is question getting deleted and other is every reference of question getting deleted, making it in effect inaccessible.

Comment: 1. "Automatic deletion doesn't kick in immediately. If you take none of the opportunities you're given, you don't get to complain once it's over." I have already addressed this many times, who decides that the changes I have edited the question enough or not. THE PEOPLE, its people who downvoted my question are the ones who decide the edits I have made is enough to lift the deletion, **the question is in the hands of people who downvoted it despite me doing everything, unless bending in every way to appease the downvoters.**

Comment: 2. Again why are **you** for deleting **my**private references of **my own** question because **you** think its bad. Don't mix these two things.

Comment: "No it's not. I can ask a very respectful question about pancakes on the Physics SE."  Again that is not what I am saying, in my opinion there is different between Big Bang theory, Steady state theory and a pan cake. pancake, until its physical attributes questioned, has no place in physics. But you can't bar me from posting about Steady state theory and then saying its a physics website

Comment: That strays into what's appropriate for the specific site. That goes on their meta.

Comment: Yes, but for some reason people there say its the concern of people here and people here say its the the concern of their

Comment: @ChakrapaniNRao No, you're missing our intent when we directed to the main meta (the site we're presently on). Your question doesn't argue that your physics questions were well-written and on-topic. It's about the deletion of comments, the mod responses, and the question ban. Those are rules which are implemented on all sites, so they belong here. If you're challenging the premise that your questions weren't upvote-worthy, that's definitely content for Physics meta.

Comment: Here's the way for you to decide where you should be posting stuff: on Meta (here), the audience is made up of people from sites other than physics. They do not know what's on-topic on Physics. On Physics Meta, where you posted your first version of this, the audience knows about the Physics site etiquette, but does not have the power to change things which affect other sites which deal with non-physics stuff.

Answer (score 17):

Saying that's how it always worked is just a tiny bit of a cop-out.

It's worth thinking of the broader implications of what happened.

> I asked this question which I later learned was apparently preposterous and was heavily downvoted.

That's part of the inherent quality of the quality control system here. Folks downvote questions they felt lacked research, or presumably are preposterous. This blog post goes in [depth into it](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/17/the-stack-overflow-question-lifecycle/), but more or less...

That's part of helping folks find quality Q&A

> But then I get a private message from moderators, that such commenting is not in line with the spirit of the website and I should instead ask in meta site or a chat room, which I found completely justified, so I messaged them back apologizing and told them that I would delete the comments that I posted on my questions requesting the undeletion and I go onto delete the comments, again to my surprise all of my comments are deleted without my permission.

So... you were aware the comments should be deleted.. and are outraged they were?

> By deleting a question you are removing a data sample from the public access and I believe it is a violent invasion of freedom of speech.

erm. [I have an answer covering that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269597/135565) - you have no promise, implicit or explicit guaranteeing freedom of speech.

> If I did not have the link to my own question somehow, I would have lost my question, I could have had some potentially valuable information or insight in that question.

Yes, this sucks. Many mods do actually sometimes help users get lists of deleted questions so they can look it up.

> This is way better solution as compared to ban someone who has asked like 10 questions in my case.

Wait, did you ask one question or 10? How did these other questions fare?

> In summary

You get why these rules are there really clearly. Much more so than many - you just seem convinced they shouldn't apply to you.

> And I also speculate if Einstein was to be born in this day and age and asks something which is non-populistic, he will not be discussed with, instead his questions will be downvoted, he will be banned from asking questions, his questions will be wiped clean by the "routine" in turn operated by "moderators". This is not Science, this is online-mob-censoring.

I half suspect he'd find it *hilarious* - considering some of the reactions to his theories. Besides, wasn't he a patent clerk before becoming the world famous physicist?

Comment: I knew I had to delete my comments but I was startled that some one could delete my comments without my permission, I didn't know that. It's one thing me telling you to delete your answer and you acknowledging it and its totally a different thing altogether if I delete your answer without you knowing it. But then I was informed it was what "comment" was. So I stand corrected on the comment issue

Comment: "erm. I have an answer covering that - you have no promise, implicit or explicit guaranteeing freedom of speech." And that's what I said is not beneficial. I need to read that long answer

Comment: "Wait, did you ask one question or 10? How did these other questions fare?" most of them have "done good" in respect of upvotes. It this and I believe one more question which was deleted.

Comment: "I half suspect he'd find it hilarious - considering some of the reactions to his theories. Besides, wasn't he a patent clerk before becoming the world famous physicist?" I was trying to point out that if Einstein tried asking some questions about absolute nature of time he would have been shunned. And it has little to do with him being a patent clerk

Comment: You have six deleted questions. All of them were closed and then deleted because they were abandoned @ChakrapaniNRao

Comment: @Catija wow, this what I am afraid of. Me forgetting what I have done. This why I plead atleast don't remove the question from my personal profile

Comment: @Catija thanks, I have no recollection of it. Can you please post the links, I would be very grateful

Comment: The other questions were basically identical to the one linked here, as I recall (OP's characterization is [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10919#comment41866_10919)) and they had similar receptions in terms of score (several of the others had many more downvotes?), closure, and being abandoned by OP. It was pretty close to crossing the line over into spam territory, and it showed a complete disregard for the feedback given on previous questions when posting the new ones. A question ban stemming from those is unsurprising.

Comment: @ChakrapaniNRao To make it clear, you only get altogether banned if you have a *history* of asking poorly-received questions. Prior to that, you're warned of an impending ban, and you're subject to short rate-limits. It's only if you ignore *all* of these preliminary signs that you get altogether banned.